# MySql Database Design For Comment System

Tags: mysql

I am working on a comment system. You have to login into your account to comment on something. Each user has its own database, that is their username. In the database their is tables that store info. For example there will be a "about" table and a "activity" table. Is this the best way setup the database? Is it even secure? Please help.

Comment: Sounds like you are going wrong right from the start here: _“Each user has its own database”_ – _why_ would each user have their own database? (Did you really mean database, or did you mean table? Even the latter would make little sense though.)

Comment: No, I mean database. I don't know how I could get each users info without making a database, with the name being their username, and having tables to store the info. How should I set it up?

Comment: If that is your current knowledge level, then you should go read some books on proper database design first.

Comment: Okay. But is it a good idea to have one big database, or many small ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want a database per user, you want a userid column in your tables.

```
CREATE TABLE about (
   userid INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   about_text TEXT
);
```

And you want to use userids instead of usernames to allow for changing or correcting usernames in the future without affecting a lot of tables. Your users table will map userid to usernames:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   userid INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE comments (
   userid INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   message_heading VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   message_body TEXT NOT NULL,
   created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

And so forth.

Comment: Okay. But I can't understand how to make a following table. If a user wanted to follow a post or there were people following the user's post. How can the user can see who is following his/her's post. I can't figure out how the DB design will look like.

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem on using a single database? Think about how many databases you will have in time when there's over a thousand users.

With a single database you save setting up every conection to all the fragmented databases. Those tables you mention (about and activity) can save all the information of a single user with the user id, if you use a foreign key on them.

Guess a good start would be (I'm only putting the "base fields", feel free to add as much as you need):

```
TABLE Users (userid, pass)

TABLE Post (postid)

TABLE Comment (commentid, comment, score, userid, postid)
```

Comment: So, if I wanted to get a comment from a user, then I would have to get the "id" of the user and get the "id" of the comment which matches the user's id? Which the comment id is set to match the user's id, not auto-incremented by one. Is this right?

Comment: When you want to retrieve all the comments from a particular user, you make a query matching the userid in the table Comment with the userid in the table Users